# When i am trying to Render data into the table it throws null is not object in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-table

```
 <Table borderStyle={{borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
          {
              tableData.map((rowData, index) =>

               (
               <View>

                <Row
                  key={index}
                  data={rowData}
                  widthArr={state.widthArr}
                  style={[styles.row, index%2 && {backgroundColor: 
       '#F7F6E7'}]}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />

                </View>
              ))
            }
          </Table>
```

here is the Json Response data

```
    var tableData = [
        {
      "activityType": "RUNNING",
      "averageHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute": 132,
      "comments": "",
     "durationInSeconds": 4915,
     "id": "2672760140",
     "startTimeInSeconds": 1525437416,
     "startTimeOffsetInSeconds": -14400,
     "summaryId": "2672760140",
     },
      {
     "activityType": "OTHER",
     "averageHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute": 106,
     "comments": "",
     "durationInSeconds": 60,
     "id": "2672781872",
     "startTimeInSeconds": 1525442382,
     "startTimeOffsetInSeconds": -14400,
     "summaryId": "2672781872",
    },
  ]
```

When i am try to map this array into the Row It Throws the Null is not an object error. Could you please suggest the solution to this problem

Comment: Have you tried logging out what the `rowData` values are?

Comment: I print the rowData values in console. that having the actual values that has in Object
"RUNNING
132
null
4915
2672760140"
... like this

Comment: can you please show code of your `Row` component ?

Comment: if your using same `JSON` as above then you are trying to use `comments` which is null and you treating it as `Object` or 'Array`

Comment: `Here is the Json Response data` - this suggests you're making an asynchronous request to retrieve the data. Is that the case? What do you initialise `tableData` to being, whilst you wait for a response?

Comment: Actually I am getting that JSON data from the API